# C# Reflection - Type error

Tags: c#, reflection, ektron

```
string assembly = "Ektron.Cms.ObjectFactory.dll";
string asspath = path + "bin\\" + assembly;
Assembly run_obj = Assembly.LoadFrom(@asspath);
paraObj[0] = run_obj.GetType(
    "Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchContentProperty",
    true,
    true
).GetProperty("Language");

string equalExp = "Ektron.Cms.Search.Expressions.EqualsExpression";
Type objclass = run_obj.GetType(equalExp, true, true);       
object objObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objclass, paraObj);
```

`Activator.CreateInstance(objclass, paraObj)` throws an error:

> System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo can't be implicitly convert
>   into Ektron.Cms.Search.Expresions.PropertyExpression

Comment: What is `paraObj` in the above code snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

The value stored in `paraObj[0]` is of type `RuntimeParameterInfo`, whereas the constructor for `EqualsExpression` expects an object of type `PropertyExpression`. You need to ensure that the types of the objects in `paraObj` can be bound to a suitable constructor for Activator to be able to instantiate a new object.

To resolve your problem you need to create an instance of `PropertyExpression` and use this as the first element in your `paraObj` array:

```
string assembly = "Ektron.Cms.ObjectFactory.dll";
string asspath = path + "bin\\" + assembly;
Assembly run_obj = Assembly.LoadFrom(@asspath);

PropertyInfo propertyInfo = run_obj.GetType("Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchContentProperty", true, true).GetProperty("Language");
PropertyExpression propertyExpression = new PropertyExpression(propertyInfo); // create the property expression here, I am unsure how to instantiate it.
paraObj[0] = propertyExpression;
paraObj[1] = longValue;

string equalExp = "Ektron.Cms.Search.Expressions.EqualsExpression";
Type objclass = run_obj.GetType(equalExp, true, true);       
object objObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objclass, paraObj);
```

Comment: EqualsExpression(PropertyExpression, long), The long property is acceptable rather the PropertyExpression value fetch by the reflection is not acceptable by the CreateInstance. Kindly give some solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying the type the Constructor is expecting from your code, it's clear that you are passing `PropertyInfo`.

If you need a value from the property the `PropertyInfo` is pointing to you would have to use 
[PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx)

I'm speculating (as I do not have the Ektron code) from your code snippet, you should do something similar to this -

```
var propInfo  = run_obj.GetType(
                  "Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchContentProperty",
                   true,true).GetProperty("Language");

paraObj[0] = propInfo.GetValue(null,null)  //depending on the requirement
```